# Problemas com o CSS do Bootstrap no DOMPDF

Tags: php, mysql, dompdf

Estou utilizando o `DOMPDF` para imprimir um CV que pega os dados através de `$_GET` da URL.

Quando eu "imprimo" o arquivo na tela, apenas o `HTML`, consigo obter exatamente o que preciso, porém, quando eu tento rodar o `DOMPDF`com o CSS em outro local, ele não gera, gera apenas uma tela em branco...

Como eu consigo fazer o `DOMPDF` entender esta folha de estilos?

Tentei também adicionar o CSS inline, porém, ele não reconhece coisas como o `float` por exemplo...

Alguém consegue me dar uma ajuda em relação a utilização do CSS externo com o DOMPDF? É obrigatório que eu utilize ele, não posso usar outra coisa como o html2pdf por exemplo.

Segue o meu código:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$var1 = "";
$var2 = "";
$var3 = "";
$var5 = "";
$var6 = "";
$var7 = "";
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

include('../conexao.php');

$cpf = $_GET['cpf'];

$result_nome = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM profissionais WHERE cpf='$cpf'");
    while($dados = mysqli_fetch_object($result_nome)) {
        global $nome;
        $nome = $dados->nome;
        $var1 .= '
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card_CV col-md-10 col-xs-10 col-ls-10 offset-md-1">
                <div class="row justify-content-sm-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-11 text-center image-print"float:left; >
                        <div class="col text-center"><img class="imgCV mt-2" src="../imagem/perfil/'.$dados->foto.'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-center name-print">
                        <div><h3 class="mt-5">'.$dados->nome.'</h3>
                        <h5 class="text-info mt-2">'.$dados->profissao.'</h5></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-center dados-print">
                        <div><label class="mt-4"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt mr-2"></i>'.$dados->cidade.' - '.$dados->estado.' </label></div>
                        <div><label class=""><i class="fas fa-phone-volume mr-2"></i>'.$dados->telefone.'</label></div>
                        <div><label class=""><i class="fas fa-envelope mr-2"></i>'.$dados->email.'</label></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mt-5 ml-2">
                    <div class="col-11"><h4><i class="fas fa-bookmark mr-3"></i>Apresentação</h4></div>
                    <div class="col-12"><p>'.$dados->apresentacao.'</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ';
    }
    $var1 .= '<div class="card_CV col-md-10 col-xs-10 col-ls-10 mt-3 offset-md-1">
        <div class="row col mt-2 justify-content-end">
            <h4 class="mr-auto ml-4">Formação Academica</h4>
        </div>';
         $var1;
    $result_formacao = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM formacaoacademica WHERE cpf='$cpf'");
    while($formacao = mysqli_fetch_object($result_formacao)) {
        $var2 .= '
            <div class=" col-12">
                <div class="card mb-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6"><h5 class="card-title">'.$formacao->escola.'</h5>
                            </div>
                        <div class="row col-12">
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle font-weight-normal mb-2 text-muted">'.$formacao->curso.'</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row col-12">
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle font-italic mb-2 text-info">'.$formacao->anoinicio.' - '.$formacao->anotermino.'</h6>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ';
    }
     $var2;
     $var3 .= '</div>
    <div class="card_CV col-md-10 col-xs-10 col-ls-10 mt-3 offset-md-1">
        <div class="row col mt-2 justify-content-end">
            <h4 class="mr-auto ml-4">Licenças e certificados</h4>
        </div>';
    $result_certificados = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM certificadosprofi WHERE cpf='$cpf'");
    while($certificado = mysqli_fetch_object($result_certificados)) {
        $var5 .= '
            <div class=" col-12">
                <div class="card mb-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6"><h5 class="card-title">'.$certificado->curso.'</h5>
                            </div>
                        <div class="row col-12">
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle font-weight-normal mb-2 text-muted">'.$certificado->escola.'</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row col-12">
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle font-italic mb-2 text-info">'.implode('/', array_reverse(explode('-', $certificado->data))).'</h6>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ';
    }
     $var5;
     $var6 .= '</div>
    <div class="card_CV col-md-10 col-xs-10 col-ls-10 mt-3 offset-md-1" style="margin-bottom: 3%; padding-bottom: 2%">
        <div class="row col mt-2 justify-content-end">
            <h4 class="mr-auto ml-4">Experiência Profissional</h4>
        </div>';
    $result_experiencia = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM experienciaprofissional WHERE cpf='$cpf'");
    while($experiencia = mysqli_fetch_object($result_experiencia)) {
        $var7 .= '
            <div class="card-body" style="background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125)">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <h5 class="card-title">'.$experiencia->empresa.'</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row col-12">
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle font-weight-normal mb-2 text-muted">'.$experiencia->funcao.'</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="row col-12">
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle font-italic mb-2 text-info">'.implode('/', array_reverse(explode('-', $experiencia->admissao))).' - '.implode('/', array_reverse(explode('-', $experiencia->demissao))).'</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="row col-12">
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle font-weight-normal mb-3 mt-2 text-muted">'.$experiencia->localidade.'</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="row col-12">
                    <p class="mb-2">'.$experiencia->responsabilidade.'</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
    </html>
        ';
    }
     $var7;

$encoding = mb_internal_encoding();
//$encoding = mb_internal_encoding();

$content = $var1 . $var2 . $var3 . $var5 . $var6 . $var7;

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

//$dompdf->set_base_path("public_html/css/");

// Carrega seu HTML
$dompdf->load_html($content);

//Renderizar o html
$dompdf->render();

//Exibir a página
$dompdf->stream(
    $nome."cv.pdf",
    array(
        "Attachment" => false //Para realizar o download somente alterar para true
    )
);

?>
```

Comment: Isso é sintoma de erro no código. Já debugou isso no log? Tem alguma coisa que não está deixando a biblioteca renderizar a saída do PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que você precisa informar o caminho do css para o Dompdf

**tipo se o boostrap estiver externamente, como CND do bootstrap, precisa ativar no domPdf**

```
$options->set('isRemoteEnabled', TRUE);
```

**se estiver em local, precisa informar onde, com** set_base_path():

```
$dompdf->set_base_path("caminho/pasta-com-bootstrap");
```

**tipo com esse exemplo automático:**

```
$dompdf->set_base_path(realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'pasta-com-bootstrap/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Por que não utilizar uma URL absoluta, como a do próprio repositório do Bootstrap? Meu primeiro palpite é que talvez, o DOMPDF não esteja localizando o caminho relativo `../css/bootstrap.css`.

Outra coisa importante é que você envolva todo o seu conteúdo que está em `body` em uma div com a classe `container` ou `container-fluid`, como é requisitado pelo Bootstrap.

Certifique-se de que todos os [requisitos do DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#requirements) estão sendo atendidos no seu servidor (local/produção). E ative todas as mensagens de erro/warnings do PHP, para saber se o DOMPDF está fazendo algum output.

Comment: Olá Macário,

Todos os requisitos são preenchidos, quando mando "printar" o conteúdo, ele consegue montar tudo da forma correta, mas quando mando ele gerar o PDF, ele não está conseguindo gerar. Ele gera apenas uma página em branco.

Comment: Você conseguiu obter alguma informação dos logs do Apache? Pode ser que encontre algo por lá.